# Merging nested array in JavaScript with id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a JavaScript beginner. I want to merge a nested array with "id" <-- unique for all the array of objects. The A and B keys are dynamic (ex. A, B, C, D, and so on) and can be added later. Whereas the dummy key is of a kind where if the dummy value of all the 3 arrays matches then only it will show in the final result; else it will show as - (hyphen)

```
let arr1 = [
  {
    A: 0.71,
    B: 0.52,
    id: 1,
    dummy: 1,
  },
  {
    A: 0.72,
    B: 0.50,
    id: 2,
    dummy: 1,
  },
];

let arr2 = [
  {
    A: 0.157,
    B: 0.02255,
    id: 1,
    dummy: 1,
  },
  {
    A: 0.16761,
    B: 0.028281,
    id: 2,
    dummy: 1,
  },
];

let arr3 = [
  {
    A: 0.55,
    B: 0.50,
    id: 1,
    dummy: 1,
  },
  {
    A: 0.5,
    B: 0.43,
    id: 2,
    dummy: 1,
  },
];
```

I want these in one array as finalArray with contains id and all the three arrays inside those with their respective ids

```
let finalArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    dummy: 1,
    arr1_A: 0.71,
    arr1_B: 0.52,
    arr2_A: 0.157,
    arr2_B: 0.02255,
    arr3_A: 0.55,
    arr3_B: 0.5,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    dummy: 1,
    arr1_A: 0.72,
    arr1_B: 0.5,
    arr2_A: 0.16761,
    arr2_B: 0.028281,
    arr3_A: 0.5,
    arr3_B: 0.43,
  },
];
```

Comment: What if the value of dummy differs for same id?

Comment: dummy value can be any integer.

Comment: What about naming the arrays in your finalArr? `arr` followed by a consecutive number?

Comment: If the dummy can be any integer than your desired output cannot hold multiple dummy values per id

Comment: per id, there is only one dummy value. (eg. id:1 dummy:7 now this will be the same for all three arrays having id: 1)

Comment: that means you get the dummy value of the first item with id = 1 right ?

Comment: @PeterThoeny 
Can you tell me if i want to merge everything in one object. Here I need to validate if dummy is same then we will print dummy else - (hypen) The A, B keys are dynamic. I have updated the Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the items by `id`.

First we'd gather up each array into an `inputs` object, combining the name and value of each array.

We can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) along with .reduce() to iterate over our inputs.

A mapping object will be created with one entry for each `id` and a dummy value corresponding to the initial value for that id. If the dummy value for an id changes, we flag it with '-'.

We add a property to each value at `id` with the naming convention `${arr}_${prop}` for each property in each iterated object.

We can finally use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the result as an array rather than an object.

```js
const arr1 = [ { A: 0.71, B: 0.52, id: 1, dummy: 1, }, { A: 0.72, B: 0.50, id: 2, dummy: 1, }, ];
const arr2 = [ { A: 0.157, B: 0.02255, id: 1, dummy: 1, }, { A: 0.16761, B: 0.028281, id: 2, dummy: 1, }, ];
const arr3 = [ { A: 0.55, B: 0.50, id: 1, dummy: 1, }, { A: 0.5, B: 0.43, id: 2, dummy: 1, }, ]; 

const inputs = { arr1, arr2, arr3 };

const result = Object.values(Object.entries(inputs).reduce((acc, [key, arr]) => { 
    return arr.reduce((acc, { id, dummy, ...obj}) => {
        acc[id] = acc[id] || { id, dummy };
        for(let prop in obj) {
            acc[id][`${key}_${prop}`] = obj[prop];
        }
        if (dummy !== acc[id].dummy) {
            acc[id].dummy = '-';
        }
        return acc;
    }, acc);
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first gather the data by id using a `.reduce()`, then transform the data into your desired array format:

**UPDATE 2022-12-09:** C\I changed below code based on changed requirements by OP:

- "I need to validate if dummy is same then we will print dummy else - (hypen)"
- OP also changed the desired output from `"arr1": { "A": 0.71, "B": 0.52 },` to a flat `"arr1_A": 0.71, "arr1_B": 0.52,`

```js
let arr1 = [
  { A: 0.71, B: 0.52, id: 1, dummy: 1, },
  { A: 0.72, B: 0.50, id: 2, dummy: 1, },
];
let arr2 = [
  { A: 0.157,   B: 0.02255,  id: 1, dummy: 1, },
  { A: 0.16761, B: 0.028281, id: 2, dummy: 1, },
];
let arr3 = [
  { A: 0.55, B: 0.50, id: 1, dummy: 1, },
  { A: 0.5,  B: 0.43, id: 2, dummy: 99, },
];

let idMap = arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3).reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if(!acc[obj.id]) {
    acc[obj.id] = {
      dummy: obj.dummy,
      arrs: []
    }
  }
  if(obj.dummy != acc[obj.id].dummy) {
    acc[obj.id].dummy = '-';
  }
  acc[obj.id].arrs.push({ A: obj.A, B: obj.B });
  return acc;
}, {});
let finalArr = Object.keys(idMap).map(id => {
  let obj = {
    id: id,
    dummy: idMap[id].dummy
  };
  let idx = 1;
  idMap[id].arrs.forEach(o => {
    Object.keys(o).map(p => {
      obj['arr' + idx + '_' + p] = o[p];
    });
    idx++;
  });
  return obj;
});
console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The same solution without ***map*** and ***reduce*** methods for old browsers as well

```
let arr1 = [
  { A: 0.71, B: 0.52, id: 1, dummy: 1, },
  { A: 0.72, B: 0.50, id: 2, dummy: 1, },
];
let arr2 = [
  { A: 0.157,   B: 0.02255,  id: 1, dummy: 1, },
  { A: 0.16761, B: 0.028281, id: 2, dummy: 1, },
];
let arr3 = [
  { A: 0.55, B: 0.50, id: 1, dummy: 1, },
  { A: 0.5,  B: 0.43, id: 2, dummy: 1, },
];

let finalArr = []
let keysToUse = ['id', 'dummy'];
let countOfIds = arr1.length;
let ids = arr1.map(d => d.id);
let varArrayToUse = ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'];
// console.log('len '+countOfIds)

for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
    finalArr[i] = {
        id: arr1[i].id,
        dummy: arr1[i].dummy,
    }

    for(var j = 0; j < varArrayToUse.length; j++) {
        if (j == 0) { targetArr = arr1 } else if (j == 1) {targetArr = arr2} else {targetArr = arr3}
        finalArr[i][varArrayToUse[j]] =  
            {
                A: (targetArr[i]).A,
                B: (targetArr[i]).B
            }                
    }
}
console.log(finalArr)
```